# How to force positioned elements to stay withing viewable browser area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a script which inserts "popup" elements into the DOM. It sets their `top` and `left` css properties relative to mouse coordinates on a click event. It works great except that the height of these "popup" elements are variable and some of them extend beyond the viewable area of the browser window. I would like to avoid this.

[image]

Here's what I have so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("area").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var relativeX = e.pageX - offset.left;
            var relativeY = e.pageY - offset.top;

            // 'responseText' is the "popup" HTML fragment
            $.get($(this).attr("href"), function (responseText) {
                $(responseText).css({
                    top: relativeY,
                    left: relativeX
                }).appendTo("#territories");

                // Need to be able to determine
                // viewable area width and height
                // so that I can check if the "popup" 
                // extends beyond.

                $(".popup .close").click(function () {
                    $(this).closest(".popup").remove();
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Love the picture -- how would you like to fix it? Make it shorter? Make it simply use it as a border? Flip the other direction?

Comment: Basically I just want to 'try' to force all the outer edges of the popup elements to be inside the visible area.  For example. If the bottom edge of one of the popups extended beyond the visible area by 50px, I would like to move it -50px towards the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution. I added the following code in the place of my 4 line comment in the original question.

```
var diffY = (popup.offset().top + popup.outerHeight(true)) - $(window).height();
if (diffY > 0) {
  popup.css({ top: relativeY - diffY });
}

var diffX = (popup.offset().left + popup.outerWidth(true)) - $(window).width();
if (diffX > 0) {
  popup.css({ left: relativeX - diffX });
}
```

**@liquidleaf** pointed me in the right direction, so +1 and thanks for that.

Answer (score 7):

You would compare the window width/height to the window's scrollTop, scrollLeft, etc.

Here are some methods for you to take a look at:

```
$(window).width()
$(window).height()
$(window).scrollTop()
$(window).scrollLeft()
$(window).scrollWidth()
$(window).scrollHeight()
```

Take a look at the jQuery documentation on these methods.  Depending on exactly the behavior you want, you'll need to compare the width and position of your popup with the currently visible area of the window, determined with the scroll dimensions.

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ .. etc

Comment: Using the jQuery methods are probably more desirable than using regular Javascript attributes (like pageX etc) - because these values vary depending on browser support.

Comment: There is no scrollWidth() or scrollHeight() methods in jQuery. Therefore this didn't end up being all that helpful. Accepted answer removed.